# Why form serialize does not work in this case?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, javascriptserializer

I have a form which I wanna send via AJAX so I'll use serialize jQuery function.

This is the code (not all the elements has "name", but anyway the alert should display something):

**http://jsfiddle.net/T6Rz3/2/**

---

JS

```
$('#add-producto').click(function (e) {

    alert($('#datos-add').serialize())

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertar.php",
        data: $('#datos-add').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });


    e.preventDefault();

});
```

HTML

```
<form id="#datos-add">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal modal-block">
            <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>Añadir productos</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Marca</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Producto</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="descr" id="descr" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Tallajes</label>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input id="tallajes" value="España">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Referencias</label>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input id="referencias" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Número de tallas</label>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input type="number" min="1" max="99" value="5" id="numero-tallas" class="span1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Primera talla</label>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input type="text" id="primera-talla" value="XS" class="span1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button id="borrar" class="btn" type="button">Borrar todo</button>
                    <button id="generar" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Generar tabla</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div id="formulario-medidas" class="modal modal-block">
                <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Tabla de medidas</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="tabla-medidas" class="table table-bordered"></table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="medidas-completadas" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Medidas completadas</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="formulario-tallajes" class="modal modal-block">
                <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Tabla de tallajes</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="tabla-tallajes" class="table table-bordered"></table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="add-producto" class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-danger" type="button">Añadir producto</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Any tip, advide or help will be appreciated, and if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: change `<form id="#datos-add">` to `<form id="datos-add">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form id is "datos-añadir" but your JavaScript refers to "datos-add".

[Here is a jsfiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/W6EhN/1/) that works. All I did was fix the reference:

```
$('#add-producto').click(function (e) {

    var $form = $('#datos-añadir');
    alert($form.serialize());
    return false;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realized. But I'm afraid still not works. http://jsfiddle.net/T6Rz3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, there is a typo. It should be `<form id="datos-add">` instead of `<form id="#datos-add">`.

But I also think you are serializing it the wrong way.

When you do a POST ajax call, you shoud use `.serializeArray()`, instead of `.serialize()`.

The `.serialize()` will join all key/values like a query string.
The `.serializeArray()` will include all key/values in the request.

In short, try:

```
$('#add-producto').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertar.php",
        data: $('#datos-add').serializeArray(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: AFAIK, querystring is meant for GET calls. You could use the `serialize()`, but `serializeArray()` is more appropiate. Besides, we don't know how he is recovering the data.